# Creating an array from table in crystal reports formula

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I have a very small view created (only 6 rows and 2 columns). 
I wish to read the values of the view into a 2D array using crystal reports.
Can this be achieved in using formulas in crystal reports?
If yes, how can i do that? IF not, is there any other alternative.? CANNOT USE SUB-REPORT

I am a beginner to crystal reports. Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused on why you need to read columns from database.

Pick the rows into array and use it in report.

If I am understanding wrong elaborate more on what you required exactly, I will try to help.

Comment: Picking up rows into an array can also work for me.
Please let me know how can i do this. If possible paste a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that takes the row from table and displays it in report.Create a formula add below code

```
local numberVar i1;
For i1:=1 to Count(table.field) do
(
Shared StringVar Array  a:=[Field1, Filed2 ,... Add as many fields you have];
);
```

Now create individual formulas for every column and place the forlumas side by side in details section

```
E.g
Formula 1:
Shared StringVar Array  a;

a[1];

Formula 2:
Shared StringVar Array  a;

a[2];

Report
Formula 1  formula 2 ......
```

Let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: Siva,
for some reasons, it is not reading all the row values into the array A. i always get only the first row values and nothing more. Any idea what might be wrong.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: In Array a you need to give all columns of the table if you give only one column it will give only one row. If you already gave all columns of the table then create saperate formulas for each column and place it in detail section to display. I have checked in my environment it worked fine. Change and let me know the result